# Laravel /w Docker bash scripting aliases

Tags: php, laravel, bash, docker, sh

Due to my local development being done within Docker, when I execute commands like `php artisan migrate` outside of container it breaks because `.env` holds DB connection to container which is not available from outside-container scope. I would like to avoid switching to container back and forth, so I first made a command to enter the container which is of the same name as folder:

```
dex(){ # Docker EXec

    if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
        CONTAINER=${PWD##*/}
    else
        CONTAINER=$@
    fi

    docker exec -it -uroot $CONTAINER ash
}
```

Now I wanted to upgrade my flow by adding another command which would from my terminal execute `artisan` command from within the container so that I know I am using the right `.env` context:

```
da(){ # Docker Artisan

    CONTAINER=${PWD##*/}
    COMMAND=$@

    docker exec -it -uroot $CONTAINER php artisan $COMMAND
}
```

Now when I execute `da migrate`, surely enough `php artisan migrate` runs from within the container, and `.env` variables are mapped the way I expect them to be.

Issue I have is when I want to provide flags to it.

Doing `da migrate --seed` results in

> Command "migrate --seed" is not defined.

Same happens if I do `da "migrate --seed"`. But if I execute the full command:

```
docker exec -it -uroot container_name php artisan migrate --seed
```

then it executes correctly. How can I tell bash to parse this the way I want it to?

Comment: Changing it to be ``` echo "docker exec -it -uroot ${CONTAINER} php artisan ${COMMAND}"``` it looks ok - I can only presume you've got something else interfering with it. Have you tried it with +x or putting it in a shell script calling da $@ ?

Comment: I get a `da` command not found when running it within a separate script

Comment: Define your da function at the start of the script